# Can Kafka Connect consume data from a separate kerberized Kafka instance and then route to Splunk?

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, kerberos, apache-kafka-connect, splunk

My pipeline is:

> *Kerberized Kafka* --> *Logstash (hosted on a different server)* --> *Splunk*.

Can I replace the *Logstash* component with *Kafka Connect*?

Could you point me to a resource/guide where I can use *kerberized Kafka* as a source for my *Kafka connect* (which is hosted separately)?

From the documentation, what I understood is that if *Kafka Connect* is hosted on the same cluster as that of *Kafka*, that's quite possible. But I don't have that option right now, as our Kafka cluster is multi-tenant and hence not approved for additional processes on the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Kerberos keytabs aren't commonly machine/JVM specific, so yes, Kafka Connect should be able to be configured very similarly to Logstash since both are JVM processes using native Kafka protocol.

You shouldn't run Connect on the brokers anyway

Comment: Could you point me to a resource/guide where I can use kerberized kafka as a source for my kafka connect ?

Comment: Kafka Connect is just a consumer like Logstash. There are docs on SASL here https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_gssapi.html#kconnect-long

Comment: "Kafka Connect has only one required prerequisite in order to get started; that is, a set of Kafka brokers"
So, to have KafkaConnect working on a server, we need to install/download kafka first ?

Comment: I dont understand the question. You need Kafka brokers for Logstash too...

Comment: yes, Kafka as a source is present. (even for logstash)
But can I install KafkaConnect without installing Kafka/zookeeper ?

Comment: You need a running, installed Kafka Cluster (and therefore Zookeeper) to use Kafka Connect... You should not run Connect on the same machines as Kafka/Zookeeper, if that is what you mean.

Comment: My question was - Can I run KafkaConnect on a server without having to install Kafka/Zookeeper on that server ?

Comment: I haven't seen any documentation that says that is a requirement, so not sure where you would find something saying different... If the question instead was can you download Kafka Connect binaries without also getting Kafka, then no, it is not a standalone package.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't add Kafka Connect to an existing Kafka cluster, you will have to spin up a separate Kafka Connect (Cluster or standalone).

I've written about it here: [enter link description here](http://isbyr.com/splunk-connect-for-kafka/)